# How to add a background picture to a Jit infovis spacetree

Tags: html5-canvas, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I need to add a picture to a spacetree to serve as a background to a spacetree.
I have tried several ways but succeeded at none, mainly for the following 2 reasons:
- positioning on the canvas (coordinates 0,0 do not seem to be the correct positioning. it is in the minus!)
- each time the spacetree redraws, it clear the canvas.

Any help will be sincerely appreciated.

guys, what I did is straight forward: if you use the example from the infovis spacetree, 
please add the following right after : 
    st.compute(); 
    //optional: make a translation of the tree 
    st.geom.translate(new $jit.Complex(-200, 0), "current");

```
//what I added 
//where myimage is an image I load in the DOM normally.

var ctx = st.canvas.getCtx(); 
var imageObj = document.getElementById("myimage"); 
ctx.drawImage(imageObj, -700, -500);
```

Comment: When posting to SO, it's always helpful to post the code you've tried so that we can review and point you in the right direction.

Comment: There are lots of mistakes which could cause this behavior. With the limited information you provide, we can do nothing but guess. To find out where exactly you made a mistake, you need to create a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) which demonstrates the problem and show it to us.